# How to use php date function to insert a date field of this format: MM/YYYY

Tags: php, mysql, function, date, format

I want to insert a date field into mysql of this format:  MM/YYYY using the php date function.  My string for the date field is already in this format "MM/YYYY".  So how to insert that into the database as a date field?

Comment: in short - dont. use the native mysql format in the table, reformat when you extract\display it

Comment: You cannot insert into mysql with that format, it expects `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: thats the problem, the original input comes in MM/YYYY format.  I don't have control over it.

Comment: then reformat before inserting -explode on the slash then glue back with dash

Comment: okay, then convert it back into `YYYY-MM-DD` and the reformat it how you want it displayed.  You don't even need the hyphens

Comment: what would you put for dd?  I only have MM and YYYY

Comment: You put day of the month.

Comment: if not using day, how about just 1 or 11 or 27, it really don't matter. i wanted 42, but there are no months with 42 days (yet (on earth))

Comment: i c.  I thought there was some general method for this but nvm, thanks.

Comment: If you are set on doing it, you can enable  `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES`. Look here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html. Maybe you could insert it as `2015-04-00` if you don't have a day.

Comment: don't even suggest such crazyness